# spyOn function called inside function

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, vitest

this is my code I want to test

```js
export function y(){}
export function x(){y()}
```

now in my test i want to check if x called y.
I'm already try couples of ways with no success (examples below)

```js
//not working
it('x call y', () => {
    const spy = vi.spyOn(t, 'y')
    expect(t.x()).toEqual(undefined)
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})

 it('x call y mocking way', () => {
    const mock = vi.fn().mockImplementation(t.y)
    expect(t.x()).toEqual(undefined)
    expect(mock).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

now I know i can change the way x and y implement and then test. for example, i can export object with x and y. and in the example above its super easy to do. but the point is that my real code is much bigger and not so easy to do so. is there any way to do that in the above implementation. and also mocking x itself and change the implementation of it doesn't feel right and going to far from the real thing I want to test